# Testing if ArcPy script will work with lower license level?

Tags: arcpy, error-999999, basic-license-level, advanced-license-level

I was looking at the question [Exporting feature class to SQLite database using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228028/how-to-export-feature-class-to-sqlite-database) which states at the end

> *The problem is that I cannot use feature class to feature class
>   because in basic licence I cannot copy feature from geodatabase to
>   sqlite database.*

I couldn't find documentation to back this up, so I thought I'd test it.  My thinking was that I would be able to change my license level down to *Basic* and try it out, however the ArcGIS Administrator wouldn't let me do that because I don't have a Basic license (I have Advanced license only).

[image]

So I am unable to confirm that the tools won't work with a Basic license because I can't limit the license I have to Basic level.

This got me thinking.  How do you test that an arcpy script will work at a lower license level than the one you're currently using if you don't have a lower license available to test with?

I read that you can import the lower level before importing arcpy, but this fails for me.

```
>>> import arcview
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcview.py", line 18, in <module>
    gp.setProduct("ArcView")
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>>> import arceditor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arceditor.py", line 18, in <module>
    gp.setProduct("ArcEditor")
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.ProductInfo()
u'ArcInfo'
>>>
```

Comment: You can read the manual it tells you the license level required for each process

Comment: @risail except for the quote right at the top that the user couldn't do something because he had Basic license and I couldn't find where in the documentation that it said that

Comment: It says basic http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

Comment: @risail yes it does, but it still remains that the user said he couldn't do it due to license level.  May be something specific to using SQLite.  Can't go checking the documentation for every tool every time I write a script, so would be nice to know if I can force validate license level

Comment: I don't think you *can* test a lower license level without a seat **at** the lower level.

Comment: @Vince That appears to be what I'm finding, although it does seem a bit counter-intuitive to have to buy a lower level license to test that everything works.  I guess the Advanced license isn't quite Everything in Basic plus Everything in Standard plus more.

Comment: The third-party license manager components would need to be written differently or 20% of the components in arcpy would need to be written differently to support the ability to run *as if* at a lower license level. Sounds like a worthy enhancement request to me.

Comment: @Vince There's an existing ArcGIS Idea at https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/8241 - I just added an answer to the duplicate to alert people to it so that it can hopefully garner some more votes.

Comment: This suggests that this is a bug with version 10.3. Maybe it carries over to 10.4. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119004 When I use the command aarcpy.CheckProduct('arcview') it says 'NotLicensed'. I do not get any error when I try import arcview. It seems to just ignore it. The legacy option arcpy.SetProduct('arcview') tells me 'AlreadyInitialized' yet arcpy.ProductInfo() prints 'ArcInfo.'